# Time comparison in for Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am facing a weird issue. Below is the code to create different time slots in Javascript:

```js
function secondsToTime(secs) {
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12 || 12;

  var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

  var userfriendlytime = ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + " " + ampm;

  return userfriendlytime;
}



$(document).ready(function() {

  var ptc_id = "236051";
  var ptc_date = "04/30/2021";
  var ptc_from_time = "5400";
  var ptc_to_time = "46800";
  var ptc_duration = "07";
  var ptc_duration_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_duration) * 60;
  var ptc_passing_time = "03";
  var ptc_passing_time_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_passing_time) * 60;

  var timefrom = ptc_from_time;
  var timeto = ptc_to_time;

  var slottimeto = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

  for (time = timefrom; time <= timeto;) {

    var slotfromtime = parseFloat(timefrom);
    var slottotime = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

    var a_id = slotfromtime + "" + slottotime;

    var slottime = secondsToTime(slotfromtime) + " - " + secondsToTime(slottotime)

    console.log(slottime);
    timefrom = parseFloat(slottotime) + parseFloat(ptc_passing_time_in_seconds);
    time = timefrom;

    if (parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds) > timeto) {
      break;
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am storing the time in seconds. The above code doesn't work, but when I change the timings like reducing from time and to time, the codes start working. Here is the working code:

```js
function secondsToTime(secs) {
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12 || 12;

  var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

  var userfriendlytime = ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + " " + ampm;

  return userfriendlytime;
}



$(document).ready(function() {

  var ptc_id = "236051";
  var ptc_date = "04/30/2021";
  var ptc_from_time = "10800";
  var ptc_to_time = "46800";
  var ptc_duration = "07";
  var ptc_duration_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_duration) * 60;
  var ptc_passing_time = "03";
  var ptc_passing_time_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_passing_time) * 60;

  var timefrom = ptc_from_time;
  var timeto = ptc_to_time;

  var slottimeto = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

  for (time = timefrom; time <= timeto;) {

    var slotfromtime = parseFloat(timefrom);
    var slottotime = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

    var a_id = slotfromtime + "" + slottotime;

    var slottime = secondsToTime(slotfromtime) + " - " + secondsToTime(slottotime)

    console.log(slottime);
    timefrom = parseFloat(slottotime) + parseFloat(ptc_passing_time_in_seconds);
    time = timefrom;

    if (parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds) > timeto) {
      break;
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you notice, I have just changed `ptc_from_time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program won't work correctly because you are using alphanumeric values to perform a comparison which should be numeric:

```
time <= timeto
```

Make sure that those variables contain always numeric values. Moreover, there is no need to use alphanumeric values that are going to be converted immediately to numeric. Keep your design as simple as possible: Use numeric constants and values.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it worked. I am getting all the number from user input so wanted to make sure everything is always numeric. The input are validated but still wanted to even make sure at the javascript end that all the numbers which are being passed should be numeric.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. I suggest you could create your own function `createSlots(ptc_id, ptc_date, ptc_from_time, ptc_to_time, etc)`, and the first thing it shuld do is to **convert** each parameter to its right type, through `parseInt`, `parseFloat` or so. In this way, you could call this function passing either string or numeric parameter values, in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have used double quotes for `ptc_from_time` and `ptc_to_time` and act as string literal, so the condition(`time <= timeto`) of both is false in first iteration because the first letter `5`(`time`) is greater than first letter `4`(`timeto`) which is not a number(string here) so remove the double quotes from your integer values. See the snippet below.

```js
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12 || 12;
   
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var userfriendlytime = ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + " " + ampm;
    
    return userfriendlytime;
}



$(document).ready(function() {

    var ptc_id = "236051";
    var ptc_date = "04/30/2021";
    var ptc_from_time = 5400;
    var ptc_to_time = 46800;
    var ptc_duration = 7;
    var ptc_duration_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_duration) * 60;
    var ptc_passing_time = 3;
    var ptc_passing_time_in_seconds = parseFloat(ptc_passing_time) * 60;

    var timefrom = ptc_from_time;
    var timeto = ptc_to_time;

    var slottimeto = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

    for (time = timefrom; time <= timeto;) { 

        var slotfromtime = parseFloat(timefrom);
        var slottotime = parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds);

        var a_id = slotfromtime + "" + slottotime; 

        var slottime = secondsToTime(slotfromtime) + " - " + secondsToTime(slottotime)

        console.log(slottime);
        timefrom = parseFloat(slottotime) + parseFloat(ptc_passing_time_in_seconds);
        time = timefrom;

        if (parseFloat(timefrom) + parseFloat(ptc_duration_in_seconds) > timeto) { break; }

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```